# Critical section example - Does it work?

Tags: c, operating-system, critical-section

me and my friends came across this example code online and we are arguing wether it implements a critical section or not.. Our opinions are going back and forth so we thought about asking stackoverflow.

So, do we implement a critical section here or not?

```
int flagga[2]; 

void task0(void){ 
 while(1){ 
 /* some code */ 
 flagga[0]=true; 
 while(flagga[1]==true) /*do nothing*/; 
 /* critical sektion */ 
 flagga[0]=false; 
 } 
} 

void task1(void){ 
 while(1){ 
 /* some code */ 
 flagga[1]=true; 
 while(flagga[0]==true) /*do nothing*/; 
 /* critical section */ 
 flagga[1]=false; 
 } 
} 

void main(void){ 
 flagga[0]=flagga[1]=false; 
 startThread(task0); 
 startThread(task1); 
 while(1); 
}
```

Comment: It's close. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm

Comment: Both this code and the code at Wikipedia needs to declare the file scope variables as volatile. Otherwise, bugs may occur when the compiler optimizes the code. This is because thread functions are callback functions. Therefore, some compilers can't determine whether or not a certain function has been called. To the compiler it might look as if these functions are never executed and then it makes incorrect decisions during optimization. 

And still, the volatile keyword most likely does not provide a hardware memory barrier, so I suppose there is a chance for issues on a multi-core system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffers from possible starvation: if neither task gets to the inner `while` before the other has set its `flagga` to true (which can happen if you stickily alternate between statements in each task), both will get stuck in its inner while loop.